# How can I toggle a loading indicator before or during anuglar's ng-click handler is run?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to manipulate my DOM (show/hide a loading indicator) while running a controller action that is triggered via an ng-click directive.

My code looks like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.wip = false;

// set currently listed categroy
$scope.setCurrentCategory = function( category ) {
  $scope.wip = true;
  //...expensive re-filtering here...
  $scope.wip = false;           
};
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentCategory(category);" >{{ category.name }}</a>
  <img ng-cloak ng-show="wip" src="icons/spinner-mini.gif" />
</div>
```

Now what happens is that the load indicator is only updated once the whole ng-click handling is finished, which means that the user never can see it.

How do I propagate the update to the $scope.wip to my view before the rest of the handler is executed?

Comment: could you share plunker or fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the scope digest is not called before the end of your setCurrentCategory function.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)

You could force a digest after $scope.wip = true like that :

```
$scope.setCurrentCategory = function( category ) {
  $scope.wip = true;
  $scope.digest()
  //...expensive re-filtering here...
  $scope.wip = false;           
};
```

I don't know if it's the best idea to trigger the digest in a already lifecycled function but it should work.

Another way I think to do that would be to have a scope function change the wip :

```
$scope.setCurrentCategory = function( category ) {
  $scope.toggleWip();
  //...expensive re-filtering here...
  $scope.toggleWip();           
};
$scope.toggleWip = function() {
  $scope.wip = !$scope.wip;
}
```